# Initialization of the Values in Constructor

Tags: c#, oop

Can you please tell me the difference between..the following constructor
initializations..

Here Person is a Class.. In that I am trying to initialize some values...
and I have created three properties named

"Name, Age, CanCode"

and calling one of this..

```
//Without Static

public Class Person
{

   Person[] people = {
             new Person { Name="Allen Frances", Age=11, CanCode=false },
             new Person { Name="Burke Madison", Age=50, CanCode=true }
   }

   // with Static...    
   /*
   static   Person[] people =
   {
             new Person { Name="Allen Frances", Age=11, CanCode=false },
             new Person { Name="Burke Madison", Age=50, CanCode=true }
   }
   */
   ........... 
}
```

When I am trying to initialize the the class constructor without `static` keyword.. 
it shows "Stack overFlow Exception."

when I debug the code, here when after creating the object for the Person class the 
initialization takes place more time, I don't know why ?

what I know is, if you use the `static` keyword those we initialize the constructor data
before the object creation... but here when we trying to initialize the data after 
creation of the object it showing this behavior ..

Can you please tell me why...

Comment: Please rewrite the question with the exact code examples (for instance, I don't see the `out`keyword in your code). Also, use code blocks (indentation) only for code to make the question readable.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting a stack overflow because you are inside the definition of a class called Person, and you are trying to create more objects of that same class inside it. When those Person objects are created, they try and create more Person objects also, and so on.

This recursive definition blows the stack because it is infinite and never ends.

Try defining this code block:

```
Person[] people = {
                 new Person { Name="Allen Frances", Age=11, CanCode=false },
                  new Person { Name="Burke Madison", Age=50, CanCode=true }
                    }
```

In a different part of your code, perhaps the main method?

Comment: It's worth noting that the semantics of the stack-blowing code are also incorrect, or odd at best.  An instance field in a class should hold some information about an instance of the class, or references to objects that are owned by the instance or contained in it.  A person doesn't usually contain other people!  So the fact that this code doesn't actually work isn't so troublesome.  If the OP wants to hold a list of people somewhere, it should probably be in a `People` class or a `PersonRepository` class.

Comment: Thank you For reply ., But it doesn't showing the error when i use the Static keyword why.. ?

Comment: Because static means it's tied to the class definition, not the instance. So that line will only ever be run once, not every time you create a person. Even though that works, this is the wrong place to hold the list of people, and should be done at a higher level in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Person[] people = new Person[2] {
                 new Person { Name="Allen Frances", Age=11, CanCode=false },
                  new Person { Name="Burke Madison", Age=50, CanCode=true }
                    };
```